# Android Parcelable Class - Inner classes cannot have static declarations

Tags: java, android, parcelable

I've been trying to create an Android Parcelable object but keep running into the error "Inner classes cannot have static declarations". For reference I have been looking at the official Android tutorial located [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html).

My current code is as follows:

```
public class AppDetail implements Parcelable {
    CharSequence label;
    CharSequence name;
    Drawable icon;

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        dest.writeArray(new Object[] { this.label, this.name, this.icon });
    }

    public static final Parcelable.Creator<AppDetail> CREATOR
            = new Parcelable.Creator<AppDetail>() {
        public AppDetail createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new AppDetail(in);
        }

        public AppDetail[] newArray(int size) {
            return new AppDetail[size];
        }
    };

    public AppDetail() {}

    public AppDetail(Parcel in) {
        Object[] data = in.readArray(AppDetail.class.getClassLoader());

        this.label = (String)data[0];
        this.name = (String)data[1];
        this.icon = (Drawable)data[2];
    }
}
```

I found someone else online who encountered a similar issue and concluded the compiler didn't like the static initializer block (rather than the static class itself) - I tried following this advice and declaring like this: `public static Parcelable.Creator<AppDetail> CREATOR` and initialising elsewhere - however I got the same error.

How can I get this / something workable to compile?

Comment: Is `AppDetail` itself an inner class?

Comment: Yes it is- should that matter?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Yes it is- should that matter?

Yes, because that is why you are getting your error. Your error is not due to `Parcelable.Creator<AppDetail>`, but due to `AppDetail` itself. You cannot have `static` methods or data members, like `CREATOR`, on an inner class.

The net effect of this is that classes directly implementing `Parcelable` need to be either `static` inner classes (i.e., `public static class AppDetail implements Parcelable`) or regular (non-inner) Java classes.

Based upon this implementation, just making `AppDetail` be a `public static class` should solve your problem.